# html input element will not update to for loop

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The text in the input immediately just skips to 99. Is there any way I can make it display
the i variable, while it's iterating?

```html
<input id="test" type="text">
<script>
    for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    document.getElementById("test").value = String(i);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: How slowly do you want it to appear?

Comment: I don't really want a delay, I just want the text for i to show when iterating through the loop.

Comment: If you don't delay, basically it will be too fast for human eyes to catch up with the updates.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) to call your function at whatever interval you like:

```js
let i = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  if (i < 100) {
    document.getElementById("test").value = String(i);
    i++;
  }
}, 100)
```

```html
<input id="test" type="text">
```

Your way won't work without some sort of delay because the entire loop executes in milliseconds and is too fast for the eye to see.